# jQuery - Slidetoggle works but not in Firefox

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$("#panel").click(function(){ 

event.preventDefault();
$("#panel_stats").slideToggle("slow");

});
});
</script>
```

I can confirm that this works in **Chrome** and **Safari** but somehow not in **Internet Explorer** and **Firefox**. I've already read somewhere that having a inline HTML "display:none" would work but in the end it didn't.

**Removing event.preventDefault(); did the trick, thank you all !**

Comment: or better yet a jsfiddle!

Comment: $("panel") isn't a valid selector. Missing `.` or `#` maybe? Probably a typo but need to see all the code for clarity. Also, you're using event.preventDefault but not defining event in the function arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#panel").click(function(){ 
       $("#panel_stats").slideToggle("slow");    
    });
});
</script>
```

Try removing `event.preventDefault();` also define panel to `#panel` or `.panel`

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/enve/L4nXy/

Comment: otherway you can add the parameter 'event' to the function called on 'click' like this $("#panel").click(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });

Answer (score 1):

You can keep `event.preventDefault();`

But add `event.stopPropagation();`

Then it will work in firefox and all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the .on of jQuery...

```
$("#panel").on('click', function(){ 
       $("#panel_stats").slideToggle("slow");    
});
```

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

I tried removing event.preventDefault but then it messed up the behaviour on Chrome.

I eventually did this:

```
    $(function () {
        $('.faqs dd').hide();
        $('.faqs dt')
            .click(function () {
                if (!(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1)) {
                    // not firefox
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
                $(this).next().slideToggle('normal');
            });
    });
```